# Double Click is not working on Image but working on white space near image in Tile List in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, double-click, tilelist

I'm facing a typical problem . Tile list getting data from array collection which are SWF images.

When user click on image it doesn't go to the itemDoubleClick(event) handler. But If user click on white space near Image, Control goes inside itemDoubleClick(event) handler.

If i use itemClick(event) , then it is working fine.

**Expected Result:**
When User double click on image it should load on different layout.

Code Demo is 
Mxml Part is :->

```
<mx:TileList id="imgView"
                 columnCount="3" 
                 width="100%" 
                 height="292"
                 styleName="tilelistContainer"
                 dataProvider="{imageArr}"
                                 itemRenderer="com.Images"
                 itemDoubleClick="{imageGalleryClickHandler(event)}"
                 doubleClickEnabled="true"
                 dragEnabled="true" 
                 />
```

ActionScript Code is :->

```
public function imageGalleryClickHandler(evnt:ListEvent):void
{                       
   Alert.Show("Control is in double click handler"): 

}
```

I'm fed of this, please help.

As per your Comment, I'm updating the Code of ItemRenderer. Please check this.

**Updated Code**

```
<utils:LoadingImage source="{data.value}"
                        width="100%" 
                        verticalAlign="middle"
                        horizontalAlign="center"
                        height="100%" 
                        maintainAspectRatio="true"
                                            doubleClickEnabled="true"
                        scaleContent="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This link might explain what is going on - not a solution but what might be causing it:

[Flex tilelist itemrender instance not match the dataprovider length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897019/flex-tilelist-itemrender-instance-not-match-the-dataprovider-length)

This link explaining about possibly using ITEMCLICK might help:

http://andymatthews.net/read/2009/09/20/Beginning-Flex:-TileList-using-the-itemClick-vs-click-events

Comment: I just found my answer, it was just a little trick to add rect with same height, width and BackGroundAlpha="0".After that OnitemDoubleClick start working perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this will work for event handing `{ }` binding notation not need here try remove those braces like 
`itemDoubleClick="{imageGalleryClickHandler(event)}"` to `itemDoubleClick="imageGalleryClickHandler(event)"`

```
<mx:TileList id="imgView"
                     columnCount="3" 
                     width="100%" 
                     height="292"
                     styleName="tilelistContainer"
                     dataProvider="{imageArr}"
                     itemRenderer="com.Images"
                     itemDoubleClick="imageGalleryClickHandler(event)" //Remove Curly braces
                     doubleClickEnabled="true"
                     dragEnabled="true" 
                     />
```

**Based on your comments**

you need set `doubleClickEnabled="true"` for your `itemRenderer and Image` aswell inside itemRenderer else double click event won't propagate(trigger).

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it still not working. i'm not able to understand why itemDoubleClick is not working but itemClick is working fine.
ItemDoubleClick work when i click near Image rather than on Image.

Comment: @AnujSharma if not able to solve issue show your itemRenderer Code

Comment: I've updated the ItemRenderer Code. Please check and guide me to solve this issue.